# How to increase the number of characters in top's COMMAND column?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, top

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1

When I run `top` from gnome-terminal as a maximized window, I see that entries in the "COMMAND" column don't exceed fifteen characters. (I'm not asking about the command-line mode seen by toggling <kbd>c</kbd>.)

[image: top1]

In section 3a.6 of top's `man` page, there is:

> Note: The COMMAND field, unlike most columns, is not fixed-width.  When displayed, it plus any  other  variable  width  columns will  be  allocated  all  remaining screen width (up to the maximum 512 characters).  Even so, such variable width fields could still suffer truncation.  This is especially true for this field when command lines are being displayed  (the  `c'  interactive command.)  See topic 5c. SCROLLING a Window for additional information on accessing any truncated data.

I then reduced the number of columns by using <kbd>f</kbd> and wrote to `.toprc` using <kbd>W</kbd>. On restarting `top`, there were fewer columns but still entries in the "COMMAND" column didn't exceed fifteen characters.

[image: top2]

So how does one increase the characters in the "COMMAND" column  from fifteen to, for example, twenty-five?

Comment: Maybe `htop` is an alternative.